# Редактирование сообщений бота telegraf

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot

Пишу бота на node.js с библиотекой telegraf. Нужно изменять сообщение которое перед этим отправил бот, все не могу это сделать

```
bot.hears('привет', async (ctx) =>{
  try{
    await ctx.reply('приветик')
    ctx.editMessageText(ctx.from.id, ctx.from.message.id, "EDIT_TEXT")
  }catch(e){
    console.log(e)
  }
})
```

не знаю откуда взять id сообщения которое отправил бот.

При заупске получаю:

```
TypeError: Telegraf: "editMessageText" isn't available for "message"
```

Comment: Текущий chatId/ messageId вы можете найти в ctx.chat.id/ctx.message.message_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно сохранить message_id при отсылании ctx.reply()

```
const { message_id } = await ctx.reply('hello')
```

Пример:

```
const { message_id } = await ctx.reply('hello')
await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 3000)
await ctx.telegram.editMessageText(ctx.chat.id, message_id, 0, 'new text')
```